# No Section error of ConfigParser in Pyspark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, submit, configparser

I have a project in pyspark in with i implemented `ConfigParser` to load some settings from `config.properties` file.

On local it work fine and without any issue so far...

But on cluster it throws No section error.

I Crawl internet and found some solution of provideing properties file to the executor throw `--files` argument of `spark-submit`

I get the file path by using 'SparkFiles.get('file')'. like this:

```
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
config.read(SparkFiles.get('file'))
```

but when i access the variable in a function using `config.get("SECTION","name")` it throws No Section error.

Here is the code flow.
In `main.py` i initalize `SparkContext`.

Then using import statement I import `Utility.py` There on the top i do this:

```
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
config.read(SparkFiles.get('file'))
```

Then in next i call a function from `Utility.py` where i try to access `config.get("SECTION","name")`. There occurs the error.

Comment: Hello ! If you want to be able to help you'll need to post a MVCE. Read about how to create one here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve !

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the properties file as config.read(SparkFiles.get('file')) if you are passing the file in --files while spark submit your job will get it by the filename itself.

Try reading config.read('file'). It works for me on yarn-client mode

Comment: is this special case in yarn or it will run on other too.